# KClass in Micronaut @Retryable annotation doesn't compile to correct class object

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I am trying to add retry logic to a micronaut client using the following annotation:

```
@Retryable(attempts = "3", delay = "100ms", includes = [ReadTimeoutException::class])
```

However kotlin compiles the `ReadTimeoutException::class` to an `AnnotationClassValue` object wrapping the actual java class. So when the retry interceptor fires it looks for a `ReadTimeoutException.class` in the `includes` array and doesn't find it.

Is there any way to force kotlin to compile the KClass to the actual java class I want?

Comment: I added a test for this and I'm not able to reproduce. There was an issue with includes/excludes prior to 1.1.0. Are you using at least that version?

Comment: Yes I am on 1.1.0

Comment: Here is an image from my debugger showing the `AnnotationClassValue` that `ReadTimeoutException::class` compiles to [https://ibb.co/vqQDS87](https://ibb.co/vqQDS87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in 1.1.1 by https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/commit/566067b72bc90f04995005502fd7bfa3aae48119